# Processing two files 32GB with python in visual studio code not processing after days

Tags: python, bigdata

I am trying to take data from specific lines in one file that is 32GB, put the extracted data in a dictionary and then read into another file of 32GB to replace specific lines with the keys and values from the dictionary created prior. Lastly, I'm trying to put all this new information in a brand new file.

However, when I ran the program, it was over 12 hours and it was still running. I implemented a progress bar and it's been 2 hours, and not one percent progress has been made. I don't get an error message, but I see no progress. Does anybody know why? Maybe it's having trouble reading files this big? Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code I used.

```
import gzip
from itertools import islice
from datetime import datetime
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):

    ## store the time the program started running
    start_time = time.time()
    ########### R1 #############

    ## create dictionary that will store the read ID as keys and barcode as values
    readID_dictionary = {}

    ## open the read 1 fastq file as R1
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R1.fastq', 'rt') as R1:
    
        ## for each line in the file, look for the read ID that starts with @ and store the read name, sequence, blank (+), and quality score as variables
        for line in R1:

            ## only perform operations if the line starts with @
            if line[0] == '@':

                ## split the lines by whitespace
                readID = line.split()

                ## store the read id for each read in a variable
                readID = readID[0]

                ## store the sequence for each read in a variable
                sequence = next(R1)

                ## store the barcode (first 20 characters)
                barcode = sequence[:20]

                ## append reads as keys and barcodes as values respectfully in dictionary
                readID_dictionary[readID] = barcode

###########################################################

########### R2 #############

    ## content that will be in new file
    new_file_content = ""

## open R2 .fastq file as R2
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_copy.fastq', 'rt') as R2:

    ## for each line in the file
        for line in R2:

        ## if the line starts with @ perform the operations
            if line[0] == '@':

            ## split the lines by whitespace
                readID = line.split()

            ## store the read ID 
                readID = readID[0]

            ## if the read ID matches the read ID from R1 (key in dictionary) then have the read ID in R2 equal that ID with _ and barcode
                for key, value in readID_dictionary.items():
                    if readID == key:
                        readID = key + '_' + value

            ## store sequence 
                sequence = next(R2)

            ## store blank (plus sign)
                blank = next(R2)

            ## store quality score
                quality = next(R2)

            ## format the content for the new file
                new_file_content += readID +'\n' + sequence + blank + quality 

###########################################################

########### NEW FILE WITH UPDATED READID+BARCODE #############

## create a new file with the updated read ID
    writing_file = open("/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_test.fastq", "w")

## put the content in the new file
    writing_file.write(new_file_content)

## close the file
    writing_file.close()

###########################################################

###########################################################

########### REPORT #############

## show how long program took to run
    print("Process finished --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

###########################################################
```

Comment: what is `tqdm`? You are running this 10000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dictionary as a dictionary not as a list,

Don't keep the new file content in memory: just write it to disk during processing

```
import gzip
from itertools import islice
from datetime import datetime
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

for i in tqdm(range(10000)):

    ## store the time the program started running
    start_time = time.time()
    ########### R1 #############

    ## create dictionary that will store the read ID as keys and barcode as values
    readID_dictionary = {}

    ## open the read 1 fastq file as R1
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R1.fastq', 'rt') as R1:
    
        ## for each line in the file, look for the read ID that starts with @ and store the read name, sequence, blank (+), and quality score as variables
        for line in R1:
            ## only perform operations if the line starts with @
            if line[0] != '@': continue
            readID = line.split()[0]
            ## store the barcode (first 20 characters of next line)
            readID_dictionary[readID] = next(R1)[:20]

###########################################################

########### R2 #############

## open R2 .fastq file as R2
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_copy.fastq', 'rt') as R2:
        with open("/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_test.fastq", "w") as newfile:
            for line in R2:
                if line[0] != '@': continue
                readID = line.split()[0]
                ## if the read ID matches the read ID from R1 (key in dictionary) then have the read ID in R2 equal that ID with _ and barcode
                if readID in readID_dictionary:
                    readID = readID + '_' + readID_dictionary[readID]
                ## store sequence 
                sequence = next(R2)
                ## store blank (plus sign)
                blank = next(R2)
                ## store quality score
                quality = next(R2)
                ## format the content for the new file
                newfile.write(readID +'\n')
                newfile.write(sequence + blank + quality)

###########################################################

########### REPORT #############

## show how long program took to run
    print("Process finished --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

###########################################################
```

Comment: You have a very good point about actually using the dictionary as a dictionary! That could improve speed immensely.

Comment: Unrelated to the core issue: I would recommend against using "continue" statements, as it's a form of goto and makes the structure unclear, making it easier for bugs to hide. It's more elegant and just as fast to use a simple indented if statement as in the original. It still works with "continue", it's just what I would consider a bad habit. I would instead extract a function if the aim is to avoid deep nesting. I say this because you explicitly changed the existing code into using continue, as if it were meant as some sort of improvement; I believe it's the opposite.

Comment: @Jesper continue is NOT a form of goto, just like a while loop could be considered a goto in disguise, a big if-tree is unreadable and I need a big screen to read, break-out/continue of the loop as early as possible, do the test on fail case and continue

Comment: If the disk is not an SSD drive it is better to put the result (newfile) on a different disk

Comment: Hi @rioV8, thanks for your answer, I'm tried it on like 4KB files and it worked, trying now on the big files. Do you know why it stays at 0% percent processing? I thought if it was a memory problem then it would show an error related to memory but it just doesn't show anything and continuously runs. Any ideas?

Comment: @IronMan18 Where do you expect this 0% to see, you only calc the total processing time

Comment: @rioV8 the package tqdm generates a progress bar. Before I implemented it, the program just ran and never stopped so I wasn’t sure where the program was in the processing. When I run with the progress bar, it just keeps saying 0%

Comment: @IronMan18 Because you use it wrong, read the doc or pypi page again, think about iterators

Comment: @rioV8 Ah, I see. Do you think splitting up the files into smaller files such as 7500MB would speed up processing or just over-complicate things?

Comment: @IronMan18 If you can keep the content of the first file in memory there is no reason to split the second one, If you need to split the first one you have a much more complex problem

Comment: @rioV8 A `while` loop is well-described in theoretical computer science and far from a goto (and yes, in machine code a loop is a goto, as is an `if` statement). I understand all your points and know why you used continue. My point was that it's an unhealthy coding style and that bugs lurk when you use it. The code structure becomes unclear. I wrote because when you change other people's code, you would need a good reason, and in this case the original was cleaner, clearer and less bug-prone. Too deep nesting is better handled by extracting functions; that improves testability too.

Comment: @Jesper Using `continue` is NOT asking for bugs, it is a perfect fine coding style, if it was not, it would be deprecated at the same time as `goto`. `break` and `continue` are better coding style then al kinds of `if` constructions. And using functions is just a way of breaking up an `if` tree and making the code harder to read just to eliminate a `continue` or two. And `goto` is not removed from many languages because there are cases where it is the only solution to use.

Comment: @rioV8 We'll just have to agree to disagree. Yes, continue is sometimes useful, but not in this case. And using functions does make the code easier to read (and even more testable) when you do it right. Using continue in this case does make the code harder to read, and it definitely does hide bugs. I'm not sure goto can be the only solution in some cases, but if so, it would be extremely rarely. So we simply disagree about these things, and I suggest we stop discussing it here. I would be happy to explain in detail, but I believe this is not the place. In conclusion: We simply disagree.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would always try to run a program on a much smaller input first (1 MB, 10 MB, 100 MB?) to see if the program works correctly, and if so, how long time it takes per MB. Then I can calculate how long time it would approximately take for the full file and how much progress would be expected at which time in the progress.

Maybe you can even make those small file tests while leaving it running on the big file, to at least see that the program actually works and will eventually finish (to not lose your current progress). Try with a very small file first (maybe the first 1 MB of the large file), then perhaps increase in size if that worked flawlessly.

Looking at the actual program, though, I would definitely *not* collect the whole data in memory and only write it in the end. I would write to the output file continously. That is much more efficient and won't use the same likely huge amount of virtual memory as you use with the current program.

So, something like this (didn't test, as I can't):

```
import gzip
from itertools import islice
from datetime import datetime
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10000)):

    ## store the time the program started running
    start_time = time.time()
    ########### R1 #############

    ## create dictionary that will store the read ID as keys and barcode as values
    readID_dictionary = {}

    ## open the read 1 fastq file as R1
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R1.fastq', 'rt') as R1:
    
        ## for each line in the file, look for the read ID that starts with @ and store the read name, sequence, blank (+), and quality score as variables
        for line in R1:

            ## only perform operations if the line starts with @
            if line[0] == '@':

                ## split the lines by whitespace
                readID = line.split()

                ## store the read id for each read in a variable
                readID = readID[0]

                ## store the sequence for each read in a variable
                sequence = next(R1)

                ## store the barcode (first 20 characters)
                barcode = sequence[:20]

                ## append reads as keys and barcodes as values respectfully in dictionary
                readID_dictionary[readID] = barcode

###########################################################

########### R2 #############

    ## content that will be in new file
    new_file_content = ""

    ## open R2 .fastq file as R2
    with open('/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_copy.fastq', 'rt') as R2:

        ## create a new file with the updated read ID
        with open("/Users/jakevazquez18/Desktop/Axel_Scripts/UMI_Tools/AD507-noCL.R2_test.fastq", "w") as writing_file:


        ## for each line in the file
            for line in R2:

            ## if the line starts with @ perform the operations
                if line[0] == '@':

                ## split the lines by whitespace
                    readID = line.split()

                ## store the read ID 
                    readID = readID[0]

                ## if the read ID matches the read ID from R1 (key in dictionary) then have the read ID in R2 equal that ID with _ and barcode
                    for key, value in readID_dictionary.items():
                        if readID == key:
                            readID = key + '_' + value

                ## store sequence 
                    sequence = next(R2)

                ## store blank (plus sign)
                    blank = next(R2)

                ## store quality score
                    quality = next(R2)

                ## format the content for the new file
                ## and put the content in the new file
                    writing_file.write(readID +'\n' + sequence + blank + quality)

###########################################################


###########################################################

########### REPORT #############

## show how long program took to run
    print("Process finished --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

###########################################################
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right about splitting up the processing. I was also looking into the chunksize parameter of .read() but the only problem is I have to read the file 4 lines at a time and starting with a line that begins with "@" so I don't want to cut off any four lines or start at the wrong position. I will try your answer out, though. I like the idea of putting the loop within a loop for the output file!

Comment: @IronMan18 No need to use .read() or chunksize; that would just be complicating things. But you could perhaps change the buffer size if you want to read more data at a time. Not quite sure how much it would help though. But take a look at rioV8's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67753392 where they mention that you can actually use the dictionary as a dictionary; this could speed up the program quite a lot, I think. I wasn't looking into the details when I answered.

Comment: thanks for telling me about chunk size, saved me time. I am trying that answer now, I'm still curious as to why the processing time was stuck on 0% for so long. I thought that if it was a memory issue then it would result in an error message but it just kept running with no progress being made for hours (even a day). Do you have any idea as to why this is?

Comment: @IronMan18 So sorry about the later answer! Life circumstances happened here which took away my focus. I understand that it's probably irrelevant now, but I would have needed to see the actual code that displayed the progress to see how the progress is measured and when it is reported/updated to understand why there was no (apparent) progress. The problem could be in the reporting itself. But again, I'm late to the party, sorry about that.